# Getting Variant product details by sending POST requests in scrapy

Tags: python, json, post, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website for product details and some of the products have variants. The product data changes when you click on the quantity and it sends a post request to get all the data. I am trying to make those requests in my spider but it doesn't return any data. Plus I am trying to add the variants to different rows in a csv file. All the answers I have found online don't help me at all and I don't know what more to do. How do I make the post request work and how do add the variant data to the output.
Here's the code:

```
import scrapy
import os
import json
from slugify import slugify

class GpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gp'
    start_urls = ['https://goldpet.pt/3-cao']
    # urls = ['https://goldpet.pt/3-cao','https://goldpet.pt/4-gato','https://goldpet.pt/7-roedor','https://goldpet.pt/6-ave','https://goldpet.pt/5-peixe','https://goldpet.pt/281-reptil']
    # for url in urls:
    #     start_urls.append(url)

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('h2.h3.product-title>a::attr(href)').extract()
        for product in products:
            product_link = product
            yield scrapy.Request(product_link, callback=self.parse_products)

        # next_page = response.css('a.next.js-search-link::attr(href)').get()
        # if next_page:
        #     yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_products(self, response):
        image_links = []
        for img in response.css('img.js-qv-product-cover::attr(src)').getall():
            image_links.append(img)
        item = {}
        item['Title'] =  response.css('h1.h1.product-title::text').get()
        item['Descrição'] = response.css('div.product-description>p::text').extract()
        item['Marca'] = response.css('img.img.img-thumbnail.manufacturer-logo::attr(alt)').get()
        if item['Marca'] is None:
            item['Marca'] = 'No brand' 
        item['Quantidade'] = response.css('span.radio-label::text').extract()
        item['Idade'] = response.xpath('//dt[text()="Idade"]/following-sibling::dd/text()').get()
        item['Porte'] = response.xpath('//dt[text()="Porte"]/following-sibling::dd/text()').get()
        item['Características'] = response.xpath('//dt[text()="Características"]/following-sibling::dd/text()').get()
        item['Gama'] = response.xpath('//dt[text()="Gama"]/following-sibling::dd/text()').get()
        item['Alimento'] = response.xpath('//dt[text()="Alimento"]/following-sibling::dd/text()').get()
        item['ean13'] = response.xpath('//dt[text()="ean13"]/following-sibling::dd/text()').get()
        item['Price'] =  response.css('div.current-price>span::text').get().replace('\xa0€','').strip()
        item['product_url'] = response.url
        item['image_urls'] = image_links

        breadcrumbs = list(filter(None, map(str.strip, response.css('li[itemprop=itemListElement]>a>span::text').extract())))
        try:
            item['category'] = breadcrumbs[0]
        except:
            item['category'] = ''
        
        try:
            item['sub_category1'] = breadcrumbs[1]
        except:
            item['sub_category1'] = ''
        
        try:
            item['sub_category2'] = breadcrumbs[2]
        except:
            item['sub_category2'] = ''

        product_img = response.css('img.js-qv-product-cover::attr(src)').getall()
        item['img_urls'] = product_img[0]
        ext = item['img_urls'].split('?')[0].rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
        filename = slugify(item['Title']) + '_1.' + ext

        item['Photo_0'] = filename
        item['Photo_Path0'] = os.path.join('product images', 'images', item['Marca'], filename)

        for i in range(10):
            item[f'Photo_{i + 1}'] = ''
            item[f'Photo_Path_{i + 1}'] = ''

        for i, image in enumerate(product_img[1:]):
            ext = image.split('?')[0].rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
            filename = slugify(item['Title']) + f'_{i + 1}.{ext}'
            

            item[f'Photo_{i + 1}'] = filename
            item[f'Photo_Path_{i + 1}'] = os.path.join('product images', 'images', item['Marca'], filename)

        variants = response.css('div.products-variants')
        if variants:
            for variant in variants:
                var_item = item.copy()
                group = response.css('li.input-container.float-xs-left label input.input-radio::attr(value)').get()
                token = response.css('div.product-actions form#add-to-cart-or-refresh input::attr(value)').get()
                product_id = response.css('input#product_page_product_id::attr(value)').get()
                customization_id = response.css('input#product_customization_id::attr(value)').get()
                ajax_url = f'https://goldpet.pt/index.php?controller=product&token=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&id_product=19107&id_customization=0&group%5B8%5D={group}&qty=1'
                payload = {"controller" : item['title']
                    ,"token" : token
                    ,"id_product" : product_id
                    ,"id_customization" : customization_id
                    ,"group%5B8%5D" : group
                    ,"qty" : '1'
                    }
                yield scrapy.Request(ajax_url,callback=self.parse_variants, method="POST", body=json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

    def parse_variants(self,response):
        yield json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: You have a typo: `div.prodcuts-variants`  should probably be `div.products-variants`.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I've fixed that but the script doesn't run the items above. Nothing is returned when I run the code and the spider runs just fine without the post requests but I need it to get the variants too.